# Wordpress nav menu category link not showing

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress project where I have show nav menu category links like this:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'menu right'));
```

I have added a new category in the admin, the new category link is not showing in the menu. What should I do about that?

Answer (score 0):

As per your question. You might have registered your menu as

`function register_my_menus() {  register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu' )
    )  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );`

And that's your code to display the Primary menu is correct `<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>`

The new category according to  the question means the new menu like primary? If so then you will have to use `wp_nav_menu()` function again to use that newly registered menu as

`<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'you_new_menu' ) ); ?>`

You can check https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/function-examination-wp_nav_menu--wp-25525

Please correct me if i am misunderstanding your question.